# How to skip test/tes-jar dependencies using mvn dependency:list command

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have written a shell script to calculate dependencies of my project. Spring Boot Cli is a first level dependency of this project and in order to create a csv file with all its dependencies I simply wget the pom file from a set of maven repo and then I run the command:
mvn dependency:list -f

Then with some formatting commands I am able to create the csv file. This approach always worked but starting from Spring Boot Cli 1.4.0 it do not work any more. I got the error you can check below.

Since my approach worked until Spring Boot Cli 1.3.2 release I compared the two pom files and I noticed the following lines have been added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now these are test dependencies and I am not interested to them. I tried to exclude using lots of coommands (here some examples):

```
mvn dependency:list -f <pom file> -DincludeScope="runtime"
mvn dependency:list -f <pom file> -DexcludeTypes="test-jar"
mvn dependency:list -f <pom file> -DskipTests
mvn dependency:list -f <pom file> -Dmaven.skip.test=true
```

But nothing worked.
How I can run "mvn dependency:list" command skipping these problematic dependencies?

Consider that my tool analyzes thousands of packages and I need a solution that is ok for all of them, I cannot implement a thing specific for Spring Boot Cli like, for example, remove that lines from POM file.

```
Look here:[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spring Boot CLI 1.4.0.RELEASE
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE-tests.jar
Downloading: http://dist.gemstone.com.s3.amazonaws.com/maven/release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-  boot-1.4.0.RELEASE-tests.jar
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE-tests.jar
Downloading: http://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE-tests.jar
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/m2-release-proxy/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE-tests.jar    [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.672 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-13T13:08:39-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/158M
[INFO] 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spring-boot-cli: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.boot:spring- boot-cli:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:tests:1.4.0.RELEASE in mavencentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: `mvn dependency:list -DincludeScope=runtime` works and does not show test dependencies. It will only show runtime and compile dependencies. Or is the issue that Maven still tries to download them? That's expected as the plugin resolves all dependencies first before filtering them.

Comment: By default test are showed unless you do not specify -DincludeScope="runtime" that according to documentation shows only runtime and compile. My problem is that it try to download the tests packages like spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE-tests.jar that obviously is not reported in any maven repository.

Comment: Why obviously? If there's a dependency on something that doesn't exist, it's a good thing that the build fails. It means the project cannot be built. But I expect the test JAR of spring-boot to exists and be a module of a multi-module project. In fact Spring Boot Cli and Spring Boot Test are both modules of the Spring Boot project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot, and in a multi-module project, you want to start commands from the root POM, especially to not have this problem.

Comment: Ok, but here the problem is that this dependency does not exist in any maven repo I checked. I opened an issue to Spring Boot that immediately was closed: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7635. What I can do to avoid this problem. PS. I modified my original post adding more text about the error. Now you can see how maven try to download them.

Comment: Yes, it is expected not to be present. It is generated by the build. As said before, this is a multi-module project with intra-module dependencies. You can't resolve the dependencies if you haven't built the modules of which another one depends. This is why you have to launch commands from the root POM, and the build is ordered so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Is there a way to tell maven to ignore that dependency? In general "test-jar" and "test" dependency. For ignore I mean they are not downloaded and not considered when dependency tree is calculated. If not, what about creating some fake file to store in my local repository?

Comment: I would first ask what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve, there is possibly a better approach to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have written a tool in shell script to calculate dependencies for a big piece of sowftare like Cloud Foundry used by our PaaS product. In this particular case I am working of Java Buildpack subcomponent that has Spring Boot Cli as 1st level dependency. So I wget its pom file and then use mvn dependency:list command to have the deps. This is the only approach I found to do that. If there is a better approach I would like to know it but consider that if this requires time to impement I still need a quick solution with the code I have imlemented so far.